# Multiple errors in C

Tags: c

I am not able to understand where I am going wrong. Please help! I am new to the website. Appreciate all the help. Thanks a lot :D

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World")
}

int factorial(int x) {
   int i;
   for(i=1; i < x; i++)
      x *= i; 
   return x;
}

int a = 9;
int b;
b = factorial(int a);
printf("%i", b);
```

[image: Error Image]

Comment: I can't see your error image, but I can see you're missing a semicolon, putting code outside any functions, and missing a prototype.

Comment: The error pretty clearly says exactly what's wrong: you're missing a `;`. Also, when you post errors here, post them as text, not code.

Comment: You have code outside of `main` and so `main` does not call the function. It does not compile.

Comment: Also seem like you treat C as Python. You can't have this function call hanging at global scope. Put them in main.

Comment: All the code at the end needs to be inside the `main()` function. And you need to move `factorial()` before `main()` or add a prototype at the top.

Comment: In addition to the above problems, your `printf` inside `main` is missing a semicolon after it.  It's also missing a newline character at the end of the format string.  Your other `printf` is missing a newline as well.

Comment: Your loop doesn't end if you keep increasing `x`

Comment: The loop happens to end on my system, but only by accident because the behaviour when `x` overflows (which it will) is undefined. It does not give the right answer for **9!**

Comment: How do I correct this? Please help.

Comment: By using another variable for the product.

Comment: Can you please correct my code? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: It looks like you have corrected to code in the question, you should keep the faulty code in the question for visitors here in the future. Indentation is ok to change but the defects should still be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have corrected the code and added some comments. I also rearranged the factorial slightly, so that it works for 0! which is 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int factorial(int x) {              // added the argument type int
    int product = 1;                // use another variable
    for(int i = 2; i <= x; i++) {
        product *= i; 
    }
    return product;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 9;
    int b;
    b = factorial(a);
    printf("%i", b);
}
```

Note that you can only generate up to 12! and after that you get overflow due to the range of a 32-bit `int`.

Comment: The factorial of 9 is 40320. The above code gives the answer 362880. I highly appreciate you taking the time to help me. :D

Comment: I think your calculator will show that 8! is 40320, and 9! is 362880. Please note that we thank contributers here by voting and/or accepting the best answer.

Comment: @iammsa factorial of 9 is 362880. the above code is working fine.

Comment: oops...my bad you are correct. greatly appreciate the help. I have ticked your answer. also thank you hanie.

Comment: Since you have rearranged the code for 0!, why don't you make it more *rearranged* so that it works on the entire domain where factorial is mathematically defined?

Comment: @iammsa why didn't this answer your question after all?

Comment: @WeatherVane There is a limitation to your answer. It doesn't work beyond a certain number.

Comment: @iammsa of course there is a limitation. If you use 64-bit variables there is another limitation, and then with 128-bit variables yet another limitation. There *isn't* a way that does not quickly hit a limitation. That is not the fault of this answer, but a result of the steep rise in value of factorials. This answer corrects the error in your code. The comment above from AC is a spoof - it's impossible to compute the entire domain of factorials.

Answer (score 2):

First here `printf("Hello World")` you are missing `;`

Second add this part to your `main`.

```
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
      int a = 9;
      int b;
      b = factorial(a);
      printf("%i", b);
}
```

and when you are calling your function in main,you shouldn't send `int a` to function `b = factorial(int a)` ,because by saying `int a` instead of `a` you are redefining it.(so it will be uninitialized,if redefinition is not error)

also as said in comments you should add a prototype for `factorial` before main or move it before main.

Finally your loop in `factorial` is infinitive ,`for(i=1; i < x; i++)` since you're doing `x *= i;`

this condition `i < x` is never true.

you will increase `x` until int type has not enough space for it. so a garbage value will be assigned to it ,and you will exit the loop.

Comment: The function definition `int factorial(x)` does compile in MSVC but it isn't conforming.

Comment: @WeatherVane  you mean about infinite loop?

Comment: No, I mean a comforming function definition is `int factorial(int x)`

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm not talking about definition of function ,I meant calling it. in first code (before edit) function was called `int a=9; b=function(int a);` I said it should `int a=9; b=function(a)`.

Comment: Yeah, it was confusing having the posted code changing, but it still contains the mistake I commented on.